# Microsoft Access runtime engine 64-bit giving error while accessing .accdb file

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access, office365, oledb

My application have access database file (.accdb) and earlier we supported access file .accdb 32-bit version with MS Access runtime engine 2013 32-bit which is working fine till now.

But now we need to support access db file (.accdb) 64-bit version, for that I've created a new .accdb file in MS Access 64-bit version(installed through office 365 pro) and imported all tables from existing db file to new db file and tried to query the db, but ended up with this error **"The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"**

Below are the complete details:

Machine details:
**Windows 7 64-bit, MS Office 365 pro 64-bit, MS Access runtime engine 2013 64-bit version, Build Framework selected as 32-bit**

My application details:

- Running platform : **Any CPU**
- .accdb connection string : **"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\ApplicationData\Data\Temp.accdb;Persist Security Info=True"**

Also I've tried changing provider details like **OLEDB.13.0, OLEDB.14.0, OLEDB.15.0, OLEDB.16.0** etc...

I've tried all the ways but don't know why I'm getting this provider is not registered error.

Comment: Does it work if you compile using `x64` instead of `Any CPU`?

Comment: I didn't find that option.

Comment: [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920). Install the `AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe`.

Comment: I've tried 2016, but again same issue coming..

Comment: Is .NET framework also should be 64-bit??

Comment: @nag [Try to add a new solution platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-edit-configurations?view=vs-2017#to-create-a-project-configuration) Now you can select `x64` and compile and test using that  setting.

Comment: The Framework bitness must be the same. If you have the `Prefer 32 bit` option selected in a 64 bit project, un-tick it.

Comment: @Jimi My target framework is selected as 32 and I tried selecting 64 bit, but the problem is few login modules using 32 bit oledb plugins where I'm getting provider 'microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0' is not registered kinda message. Any help how to overcome these situations??

Comment: Not that I know of. But, are we talking about Office Automation, or just working with a MS Acces Db? The 64/32 Bit versions of Office produce the same DataBase format. OleDb can open it anyway.

Comment: Jimi is correct. The file format does not matter if you just reading the accDB file. Both x32 and x64 data engines don't care about the file. The only issue is if you are using automation. Then all compounds used (including the access instance) MUST match your .net project bit settings. You cannot mix + match the bit size of ANY library used - they must all be the same. So accDB file format does not care or matter, but any library or components must match the "in-process" bit settings of your .net project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone for the help. Finally I've found the issue for my problem.

Actually the error I'm getting here is because the application that I'm using ACCDB database file is running on 32-bit platform and that's why I'm getting error like "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine".

After updating build platform from 32-bit to AnyCPU, everything working fine.